# d3.js Pictogram chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a pictogram application.

Here is my latest code. I am going to attempt to place a texture layer on top of the rectangular blocks. Is there way of controlling the padding for the various axis?

```
var pictogramData = [
        {
            "label": "8",
            "value": 8
        },
        {
            "label": "9",
            "value": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "10",
            "value": 9
        },
        {
            "label": "11",
            "value": 12
        }    
    ];


var margins = {
    top: 0,
    left: 30,
    right: 24,
    bottom: 0
};

var chart,
    width = 300,
    pixelGap = 2,
    bar_height = 15,
    height = ((bar_height + pixelGap) * pictogramData.length),
    gapHeights = (pixelGap) * pictogramData.length;



svg = d3.select("#step-1") 
  .append('svg');


svg
  .append('defs')
  .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', 'diagonalHatch')
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('width', 4)
    .attr('height', 4)
  .append('path')
    .attr('d', 'M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2')
    .attr('stroke', '#000000')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1);


chartWidth =  width * 0.8;

chart = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'chart')
  .attr('width', chartWidth)
  .attr('height', height+gapHeights)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')');


valueList = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
 .attr('width', width *0.2)
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width - margins.right) + ',' + margins.top + ')')


chart
.append('g')

var x, y;

var max = d3.max(pictogramData, function(d) { return +d.value;} );

    function getValueDomain(data){
        var valueDomain = new Array();

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            valueDomain.push(data[i].value);
        }
        return valueDomain;
    }

var valueArray = getValueDomain(pictogramData);

x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, max])
    .range([0, chartWidth]);

y = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .domain(valueArray)
   .rangeBands([0, height]);

    function plotRectangleGroups(groupName, pictogramData, chartWidth){
            //Add a group to hold the rects
            var group = chart.append("g")
                .attr("class", groupName+"group");

            group.selectAll("rect")
                .data(pictogramData)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", function(d, i){
                    return y(d.value) + (pixelGap*i);
                })
                .attr("width", function(d, i){
                    var barWidth = chartWidth;
                    if(
                        groupName != "base" &&
                        groupName != "pattern"
                      ){
                       barWidth = x(d.value);                     
                    }                    
                    return barWidth;
                })
                .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
            .attr('fill', function(){
                var fill;
                if(groupName == "pattern"){
                    fill = 'url(#diagonalHatch)';
                }

                return fill;
            });        


    }

plotRectangleGroups("base", pictogramData, chartWidth);
plotRectangleGroups("rects", pictogramData, chartWidth);
plotRectangleGroups("pattern", pictogramData, chartWidth);

//left labels
labels = pictogramData.map(function (d) {
    return d.label;
});

yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(labels)
        .rangeRoundBands([0, height]),    

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient('left'),    

chart.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .call(yAxis);



//right labels
values = pictogramData.map(function (d) {
    return d.value;
});

yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(values)
        .rangeRoundBands([0, height]),    

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient('right'),    


valueList
    .call(yAxis);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4zt64yj8/18/

Comment: The padding is controlled by the `margins` variable. Try decreasing the `left: 30` to a lower value and you'll see that each bar starts further to the left.

Comment: I meant the line-height of the axis, how could I be sure it aligns better with the bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misalignment of the bars and the tick labels in the Y axis comes from the `pixelGap` value.

```
pixelGap = 1,
...
.attr("y", function(d, i){
  return y(d.value) + (pixelGap*i);
})
```

As you can see the `pixelgap` is used to add a little white space between the bars, but you (or whoever created the chart) forgot to compensate for them in the range. The `pixelGap*i` means that every next bar is pushed down a bit further, while the corresponding labels are not pushed down.

Simplest fix is to remove the multiplication and modify both the `y` and the `height` attribute:

```
        group.selectAll("rect")
            .data(pictogramData)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", function(d, i){
                return y(d.value) + pixelGap;
            })
            .attr("width", function(d, i){
                var barWidth = chartWidth;
                if(
                    groupName != "base" &&
                    groupName != "pattern"
                  ){
                   barWidth = x(d.value);                     
                }                    
                return barWidth;
            })
            .attr("height", y.rangeBand() - pixelGap)
```

With this change the vertical padding is essentially equally spread out above and below the bar, which in turn gets rid of the misalignment.